# REACTJS: Change state in another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two file Reactjs
file1.js

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        selection: null
    };
```

file2.js

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
InputChange = () => {
    console.log(App.state);
}}
```

I want to use and change state of class App when using class SearchBar, i imported the file2 to file1. Thank you! My English is not good.

Comment: do file1 and file2 share any relationShip,

Comment: I would recommend to read the React guide, e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easy :D you just need to pass in the function that changes the state like so:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        selection: null
  };

  changeStuff(paramsIfAny) {
    this.setState(/* whatever you want */);
  }

  render() {
    .....
     <SearchBar changeHandler={this.changeStuff.bind(this)} />
    .....
  }
}
```

And then on your SearchBar component

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
InputChange = (params) => {
   this.props.changeHandler(params);
}}
```

This was really abbreviated code to simplify what I meant. I hope you got how it is done!